# Is translator and preprocessor the same in c?

Tags: c

I am confused by these two terms. Are they the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean "Compiler" when you say "Translator."  They are not the same.  Preprocessing is a phase of compilation.

See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor).

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor is actually run before the compiler and handles special directives like macros.

Answer (score 0):

A *preprocessor* converts a stream of text tokens into a different stream of tokens.
A *compiler* converts a stream of tokens into executable code.